# Change the user agent in windows phone 8.1 webview?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

i want to set user agent to windows phone 8.1 webview. i used external "Dll" but at time of publishing into store its failed in certification process please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
[DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        private static extern int UrlMkSetSessionOption(int dwOption, string pBuffer, int dwBufferLength, int dwReserved);

        const int URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT = 0x10000001;
        public void ChangeUserAgent(string Agent)
        {
            UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, Agent, Agent.Length, 0);
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeUserAgent("My Custom User-Agent");
            wb.Navigate(new Uri("https://basquang.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/wp8-1-changing-windows-phone-8-1-webview-default-user-agent-in-all-outbound-http-requests/", UriKind.Absolute));
        }
```

Chek [here](https://basquang.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/wp8-1-changing-windows-phone-8-1-webview-default-user-agent-in-all-outbound-http-requests/)